# How do you determine if a rule is active?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Using the example from https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Conditional-Validation-with-onlyIf-parameter

The rule is defined as:

```
self.state = ko.observable().extend({
    required: {
        onlyIf: function () {
            return self.country() === 'US';
        }
    }
});
```

It appears that doing `state.rules()[0].condition()` will tell you if the rule is active, but it doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LYP5u/64/

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is active if your validation rule is true so you could try this solution:

```
ko.validation.init();

function Address() {
  var self = this;
  self.availableCountries= ['AU', 'NZ', 'US'];
  self.availableStates =  ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas'];
  self.country = ko.observable().extend({required: true});
  self.stateRule = function(){
         return self.country() === 'US';
  }
  self.state = ko.observable().extend({
    required: {
            onlyIf: self.stateRule
        }
    });
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
};

var address = ko.validatedObservable(new Address())();
ko.applyBindings(address);
```

Test with this template:

```
<p data-bind="text: stateRule()"><p>
<p data-bind="text: state.rules()[0].condition()"><p>
<div>
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" data-bind="options: availableCountries, value: country, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
<div data-bind="visible: state.rules()[0].condition()">
    <label for="state">State</label>
    <select id="state" data-bind="options: availableStates, value: state, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/LYP5u/78/)

Comment: I don't want to know if the property is valid. I want to know if the validation rule is active. In the example, state is only required if country is 'US'. So, I'm looking for the correct method for determining the current state of the `onlyIf` condition.

Comment: Edited the answer. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I was looking for an existing property provided by the library. Similar to the `isValid` property, something like `isActive` seems useful. `rules()[0].condition()` does it for me in my example, but it seems like a hack.